# How can I launch Instagram app on button click Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just want to open Instagram application on button click (if installed) on minimum API 16.

What I am trying is:

```
Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(likeIng);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"Instagram Not Installed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But when running on a phone where Instagram is installed, it's not launching it.

Answer (score 5):

pass this this Uri to your intent.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/YOUR_USERNAME");


Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);

i.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/xxx")));
}
```

Comment: strange , this is working for me, i will  post another solution in several hours

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packageName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String))

Comment: startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android"));

Answer (score 0):

use this. I already used this.

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this method:

```
private void callInstagram() {        
    String apppackage = "com.instagram.android";
    Context cx=this;
    try {
        Intent i = cx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(apppackage);
        cx.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception  e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, Instagram Apps Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Always share an explanation and the above code does not work